# If a spellcaster's racial trait grants a spell that requires material components, can they use their class' focus to cast that spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, racial-traits, spell-components, spellcasting-focus

Based on the answer to [this question about non-spellcasters](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132731/does-a-non-spellcasting-drow-pc-need-material-components-to-cast-dancing-lights), spells granted by racial traits don't waive the need for material components.  However, can spellcasters use their class' allowed focuses with such spells, or must they still acquire the specific materials (or a component pouch) to cast them?

If the spell is also on their class' spell list, does that change anything?

Comment: Related: "[What makes a spell being cast considered to be a {class} spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106182)"

Comment: @Medix2 Thanks for finding that, I tried but failed. I have posted a new answer there too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## They cannot use a focus

The feature that allows a character to use a focus is usually Spellcasting, and it has a wording like:

> SPELLCASTING FOCUS You can use a holy symbol (found in chapter 5) as a
> spellcasting focus for your cleric spells. (PHB 58)

This indicates that you can only use those focuses for [class] spells. A spell is a [class] spell if you have learned it as a member of [class], it being on its list is not important.

A spell learned from a racial feature is not associated with any class and thus the features that grant the ability to use a focus item do not cover them.

Comment: Another reason for, given the choice, going for the "Component Pouch" rather than the focus... Just saying, just saying.

Comment: @HellSaint  I've heard that argument before -- typically from multiclassers who don't want to juggle several types of focus -- but I just prefer their flavor over the "self replenishing bag of minutiae."